# Looping Separator Data ORACLE 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am new to Oracle and I am unaware about using for loop in Oracle SQL (not PL/SQL).

I  the query and execute the statements like this:

I have the following data

```
ID   NAME    DATE          SALARY
101  5A101   100411041204  12000
```

I need the following result:

```
ID    NAME    DATE   SALARY
101   5A101   1004   12000
101   5A101   1104   12000
101   5A101   1204   12000
```

How do I create a query for that result?

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and try to ask a more clear question.

Comment: This is a horrible data model. You should never store multiple values like that in a single column.

Comment: yeah i know .. but my boss chalange me for this example .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the weird Data structure, If you want an answer anyway, It could be

```
WITH test
     AS (SELECT 101 id,'5A101' name,'100411041204' date1,12000 salary FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT 1012 id,'5A102' name,'10041104' date1,12000 salary FROM DUAL)
    SELECT DISTINCT id,
                    name,
                    SUBSTR (date1, (LEVEL - 1) * 4 + 1, 4) date1
      FROM test
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH (date1) / 4
  ORDER BY id, name, date1
```

Here the date column should have data with length multiple of 4.

Comment: yuppp only have length multiple of 4 .. thanks sir ^_^

Comment: sir .. "with" cant running in store procedure .. can u help me for store procedure just sample no problem..

Comment: I have used WITH clause only for demonstration. Instead of test you can use the actual table name where the data is present.

Answer (score 0):

You could use recursive CTE for instance:

**<sup>[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/011e9/1)</sup>**

```
with cte (id, name, date_, salary, dt, rn) as (
  select id, name, date_, salary, substr(date_, 1, 4), 1 from t
  union all
  select id, name, date_, salary, 
         substr(date_, rn * 4 + 1, 4), rn + 1 
  from cte where substr(date_, rn * 4 + 1, 4) is not null )
select id, name, dt, salary from cte 
  order by id, rn
```